# ERROR: make.exe:***No rule to make target

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

I' m a beginner in Android Programmin and Eclipse. I' m using Eclipse Luna (4.4 version). I' m imported "OpenCV - face detection" project in Eclipse, but when I try to buil it, Eclipse give me this error:

Description: make.exe: *** No rule to make target `../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk'. Stop.
Resource: OpenCV Sample - face-detection
Type: C/C++ Problem

I think the file that causes this error is Android.mk, contained in jni directory and this is its code:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

On the 8th row of previous file:

```
include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

Eclipse report me this warning:

Description: make: ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk: No such file or directory
Resource: Android.mk
Path: /OpenCV Sample - face-detection/jni
Location: line 8
Type: C/C++ Problem

Can someone help me? I'm sorry for my English XD

Answer (score 3):

The OpenCV samples are configured to use relative paths inside the SDK package, so you shouldn't use 'copy project to workspace' option when importing a project into your workspace.

In your case, you need to replace the relative path "../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk" in the Android.mk file with the full absolute path to it.

Also, you are maybe forgetting to define NDKROOT environment variable?

Follow this tutorial to import correctly and define all environment variables for native development:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html#building-application-native-part-from-eclipse-cdt-builder

Another tutorial: Go to section Native/C++ of the following document and make sure all the variables are set correctly for native development:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#native-c

Comment: Path of OpenCV.mk was wrong.I defined NDKROOT in C/C++ Build envoirment, but now I have 5 warning caused by dead code and deprecable code and this 2 warning: 1) Description: Invalid project path: Include path not found (C:\Users\Salvatore\sdk\native\jni\include) - Resource OpenCV Sample - face-detection - Location: pathentry - Type: Path Entry Problem        2) Description: Invalid project path: Include path not found (C:\Users\Salvatore\workspace\android-ndk-r10b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\include) - Resource OpenCV Sample - face-detection - Location: pathentry - Type: Path Entry Problem

Comment: First: 
     Verify that the two paths exist.

Second:
     If you are using Windows+Eclipse, try changing the backslash "\" to slash "/" in the Path and Symbols include of opencv jni libs.

Example: Wrong --> C:\Users\Salvatore\sdk\native\jni\include Correct --> C:/Users/Salvatore/sdk/native/jni/include

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but still if it helps :

> In my case I had to replace the relative path
>   "../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk" in the Android.mk file with full
>   absolute path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its OK to use relative path. In my case, I find different OS might parse path string differently.

Try replace:

```
../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

with

```
..\..\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk
```

`/` works on my Mac OS.